# How do I revisit old areas in BioShock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

This is my first time playing the game and I've played for a few hours but I want to revisit locations I've already been to. How?

Comment: Have you tried navigating through the menu system to play a previous chapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return to previous areas like in the original BioShock. The only option is to load a previous auto save and re-play the level.

Achievement counters (kills per gun, voxophones, etc.) work across saves, so you can go to old saves to work on achievements if you want.